# Include Page-Break-Inside when Copying and Pasting from IE into Word

Tags: html, css, excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to copy and paste from Internet Explorer into Word using Excel VBA.

The issue I have is that word is not *applying* the style correctly when it comes to `Page-Break-Inside` from the CSS file.

Am I missing a trick with the copying and pasting side of things or are there any other ways to replicate the function of `Page-Break-Inside`? Ultimately, none of the tables should span across two separate pages. A sample of the CSS is below:

```
table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 600px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, did you solve this problem?

Comment: @lanoxx Unfortunately not. I can't recall what I did in the end, sorry!

Comment: thanks for the reply, to looks like this is a bug in the HTML import code of MS Word, for some reasons it just seems to ignore the `page-break-inside` attribute no matter where I put it.

Comment: @lanoxx all I can remember is that I spent far too long getting no where!